# Why can't I define an Action in line in a method expecting a delegate?

Tags: delegates, c#-4.0, action

Given the following MSDN sample code, why can't I define the Action delegate "inline":

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action someAction = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello from the thread pool!");

    Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction);
}
```

...so "inline" like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Action someAction = () => Console.WriteLine("etc."));
}
```

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't valid C#:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Action someAction = () => Console.WriteLine("etc."));
}
```

Do this instead:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("etc."));
}
```

Comment: Is the fact that the Action is omitted because it's redundant ?

Comment: No... it's not valid C#. This is valid, although the `Action` is redundant: `Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(someAction = () => Console.WriteLine("etc.")));`

Comment: @Scott: It is simply the same error as `Console.WriteLine(string s = "hello");`. You can't declare a variable everywhere.

Comment: @Henk: Ah, duh.  That's right - a delegate is a type so declaring a type inside is incorrect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to delegate a variable within a method call. Just removing the variable declaration may be fine:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("etc."));
}
```

Here the `Action` is inferred not from the lambda expression itself, but from the method call it's trying to make. Normal overload resolution is performed, and the compiler tries to convert the lambda expression to the relevant parameter type. If the parameter type were just `Delegate` (e.g. `Control.Invoke`) then type inference would fail because the compiler wouldn't have any concrete target types to try to convert to.

If that doesn't work (I can't easily test it atm) then you just need a cast to tell it which delegate type the lambda expression should be converted to:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)(() => Console.WriteLine("etc.")));
}
```

To be honest though, at that point I'd prefer to see a separate variable in terms of readability.

Comment: Ah, ok, same as Quartermeister's comment about infering Action.  How did you know that the compiler would infer Action ?  Is this documented or more of a trial and error thing ?  I was trying to following MSDN spec, but I obviously got it wrong.

Comment: @Scott: I've edited my answer (the middle bit). It's all as per the specification.

Comment: Ok, great - thanks!  I will have to grab a copy of the spec and run through it again to refresh my memory.

Answer (score 2):

You are including the declaration statement, which is not a legal expression.  Try:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("etc."));
```

If you call an API where the type of the delegate can't be inferred, you can use a cast or call the delegate constructor explicitly:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)(() => Console.WriteLine("etc.")));
Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("etc.")));
```

Comment: Ok, so the C# compiler is smart enough to infer "Action", but if not, it would require a type cast ?

Comment: @Scott: This mostly happens if you have a method that takes in a Delegate, like Control.Invoke.  Since any delegate type is legal, the compiler doesn't have a way to pick one.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know tbh, but I think you can do:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate() {Console.WriteLine("etc.");});
}
```

Comment: Yes, an annonymous delegate is acceptable in .NET 2.0 and works right up to 4.0...it's just that the Task Library is 4.0 and for the code inside it's nice to use C# 3.0 lambda's.